# Encounter warning when add edge in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb-2.1

Here is my Code:

```
 OrientVertex luca = graph.addVertex(null);
 luca.setProperty("name", "John" + Integer.toString(i));

 OrientVertex marko = graph.addVertex(null);
 marko.setProperty("name", "Van Ness Ave." + Integer.toString(i + 1));

 OrientEdge lucaKnowsMarko = graph.addEdge(null, luca, marko, "knows");
 graph.commit();
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgVi1.png) is a snapshot of the same.

And then, I encountered [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdV8q.png) warning:

> WARNING: The command 'create edge type 'knows' as subclass of 'E''
>   must be executed outside an active transaction: the transaction will
>   be committed and reopen right after it. To avoid this behavior execute
>   it outside a transaction (db=test)

Googling this problem, it seems that this question is relevant to the not-transactional and transactional databases operations.

Answer (score 2):

You are working schema less, so OrientDB creates classes for you the first time you create vertexes/edges. In this case it was for the Edge class 'knows'. You can avoid this by creating classes at the beginning, or however, outside the scope of transaction. Try to execute this before your code, only once:

```
OrientGraphNoTx graph = new OrientGraphNoTx(url);
graph.createEdgeType("knows");
graph.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And I understand that the OrientGraphNoTx should be used instead of the OrientGraph。 Now, I encounter another question. I used the graph.addEdge(“knows”)， but a exception rises that "class knows already exists in current database" , Seemingly, calling the addEdge API would always casuse the creation of class. So, how should I avoid creating classes at the begining?